# Pemutations and combinations problem

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

I have this one question in statistics:

There are five women and six men in a group. From this group a committee of 4 is to be chosen. In how many ways can the committee be formed if the committee is to have at least 3 women in it?

I am not exactly sure on how to approach this question since I cannot find a way to determine how many object there will and how many times they will be taken so that I can use the combination formula. My worries is with the words `at least 3 women`, does this mean that there could be 4 women then?

Comment: Is this a homework excise? Please add `[self-study]` tag and check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: It's not evident what information you might be lacking: there are $5+6=11$ people and the committee is to have $4$ people.  What "object" are you referring to, then, where you state you don't know how many there will [be]? And you are correct that in English "at least $x$" means "$x$ or more."

Comment: I am given all the information. i am having trouble with using the formula.

Comment: I calculated the answer:315. Is it correct.

Comment: You might be having trouble because this question requires you to think about the situation and decompose the solution into a few parts.  You don't just dump the numbers into a formula.  Incidentally, since there are only $\binom{11}{4}=330$ possible committees, regardless of gender, $315$ looks quite a bit too large to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two cases:
1. There are exactly three women on the committee:

```
c(5,3)*c(6,1)=60
```

2. There are exactly four women on the committee:

   c(5,4)=5

Hence:

```
Solution = 60+5 = 65
```

Comment: Thanks for leaving exactly nothing left for the OP to do. Self-study guidelines apply to answers as well as questions http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info .

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

Okay. I said:

**How many ways committee can be formed without specification i.e No 3 women restriction e.t.c:**

c(11, 4) = 330

**After that I say:**
Number of combinations that 5 women that can be taken 3 at a time = c(5, 3) = 10

**Then I say, number of combinations that 5 women can be taken 4 at a time**
= c(5, 4) = 5

Final answer = 330 - 10 - 5 = 315

Do people agree with this?

Comment: Do you really think your calculation makes sense?  Think about it again. You might want to approach it the other way and determine how many committees there are with exactly 3 women, and how many there are with exactly 4 women.

Comment: No and no, but you only have 327 possible answers left (well, maybe 328 if you think 0 could be the answer). Think it through carefully, and show your logic. Think not only about the number of women on the committee, but also what the corresponding number of men would be. That is my last hint and correctness verdict rendering.

Comment: There can only be 1 or 0 men on the committee